# Eclipse Java Oxygen - Unable to create a class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I'm new to java. I have created a new project. I have right clicked on the default package > Selected  "New" > Selected "Class".

I was expecting a create class pop-up to show , but nothing is happening. IS there a way around this problem?

Comment: Are there entries in the Error Log view indicating what went wrong? Can you retry it with the current version?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is pretty old (you are 6 releases behind). Can you reproduce this issue in Eclipse  2019-09 (4.13)? Which Java version do you use (Java 10 and higher are not supported by that old Eclipse version)? Please show a screenshot of Eclipse with the project structure.

Comment: You are right. Issue resolved on moving to latest eclipse thanks for help